# How to create many series

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mschart

Create an object in the class "Series ema = new Series("ema");"
With the button "indicator_Click" download modal dialog.
In the window using the "ComboBox" select options: dig.type, dig.period.

```
Series ema = new Series("ema");
**********************************************
private void indicator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ModalDialogBox dig = new ModalDialogBox();
            {
                if (dig.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string formulaName = dig.type;
                    FinancialFormula formula = (FinancialFormula)Enum.Parse(typeof(FinancialFormula), formulaName, true);
                    chart1.Series.Add(ema);
                    chart1.DataManipulator.FinancialFormula(formula, dig.period, "price", "ema");
                    chart1.Series["ema"].Color = Color.Red;
                    chart1.Series["ema"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                    chart1.Series["ema"].BorderWidth = 2;
                    chart1.Series["ema"].ShadowOffset = 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Next, if the indicator is not needed, delete it.

```
private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.Series.Remove(ema);
        }
```

I need to be able to add a second, third indicator.
If I try to add a series of the second indicator, an error occurs because the indicator already exists.
You can of course create multiple objects in a class:

```
Series ema1 = new Series("ema1");
Series ema2 = new Series("ema2");
Series ema3 = new Series("ema3");
```

but I do not like this method, because I do not know in advance how many indicators will be needed
[image]

Comment: I have no idea what to want to achieve. The usual way to use Series is to add DataPoints to them. Do you have any data? What do you mean by 'indicator'?? Are the data bound to a field `price`?

Comment: Yes, " ema "data is calculated based on" price"
The indicator is what is drawn " chart1.DataManipulator.FinancialFormula (formula, dig.period, "price", " ema");".
The data "price" is getting so: chart1.Series["price"].Points.AddXY(i, h,l,o,c);
I added the picture above with explanations.
The indicator is calculated based on the parameter "c" of "price"

Comment: OK. so you want to dynamically create more Series, all bound to the data by some formula. What is keeping you? Move the Series declaration to the click and use varying series names. you will need to somehow decide on the relation/scheme for  series-name-formula and which is the one to delete.

Comment: The thing is that I create an object at the very beginning of the code.
If I create an object inside "indicator_Click", when I click" delete_Click " the object is not located.
That is, I need to create a new object with a new name every time, so that there is no situation that such an object already exists.
But how to go back to the beginning of the code to create a new object with a new name, if the object already exists?

Comment: Let's not call a Series an object, ok? You can reference each Series that is in the chart.Series collection by its name. So you can do `chart1.Series.Remove(chart1.Series[aSeriesName]);`. Just know which series you have selected currently..!

Comment: With the removal of the series is clear. How to be with the series name to give each series a new name?

Comment: Figured out instead of "ema" use "name".
Without creating an object "ema".
All of this do within "indicator_Click".
string formulaName = dig.type;
string name = formulaName + dig.period;
chart1.DataManipulator.FinancialFormula(formula, dig.period, "price", name);

Only here is how to get the names of all the series for later removal?
Or need to create another ask?

Comment: You should probably store the names in a `List<string>`. But you can also enumerate the chart.Sereis collection. For a user interface solution you may even choose to use a mouseclick and a HitTest on the legend to pick a series. Its Name property can then be used....

Comment: Thanks, TaW!
Where to tick?

Comment: Tick? As in Accept? These were just comments. I would write out a full answer but I'm still not really sure about the question..

Comment: To add an indicator, I created an object, which is wrong.
Now I realized that I need to add not an object, but a series.
Every time with a new name.
In each series will be different or " dig.type " or " dig.period", which guarantees the" uniqueness " of the name.
You only need to check that there were no identical.
If you show an example based on " List<string>", the question will be completely exhausted.